# Why synchronized is necessary in getView, what if remove it?

Tags: android, synchronized

I read the ManageApplications.java of android source code and notice this 'synchronized (entry)', I wonder is it necessary here and how does it 'Bind the data efficiently'? I think a better understanding of it may solve some of my weird problem, thank you in advance.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        // ? Bind the data efficiently with the holder
        ApplicationsState.AppEntry entry = mEntries.get(position);
        synchronized (entry) {
            holder.entry = entry;
            if (entry.label != null) {
                holder.appName.setText(entry.label);
            }
        }
        mActive.remove(convertView);
        mActive.add(convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://careerride.com/Java-what-is-synchronization.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting two values in `holder` from `entry`. If you do not synchronize, there is a chance that another thread could run `getView()` in between `holder.entry` being set and `holder.appName.setText()` being called. That would result in a bad state.

Comment: Thank your for quick reply. But I always think that getView() has nothing to do with multi-threads, is that right?

Comment: In this case, I'm not sure about why getView() would be called from two threads, but the author of the code decided to make sure the code still works properly if it does. I would venture to guess that if the author synchronized this method, then it was necessary. If you look at the code between (2.2.2_r1)[http://goo.gl/dz0Faf] and (2.3.1_r1)[http://goo.gl/mBxon6], the synchronization appears.